# Python installation - user vs. programs folder

Tags: python, installation

At my company I have Python installed in my user directory where I can install it with a poweruser. But we will be migrating to Win 10 soon, and as a rule all programs must then be approved and installed centrally from the it department.

This means that I cannot choose which version to install, and where to install it. So it will be installed in my programs folder. This means this I will have to use --user when I install modules.

Are there any other challenges when Python not installed in the user directory - for example installing Virtual Environments?

Comment: As a programmer you should be able to set up your computer however you need it to be to get your job done.

Comment: I assume it would be different, if I was employed as a developer, but alas I am just a employed in the finance dept. lucky enough to be allowed to spend time doing automation using Python. So I was used to having full control as I could install, and now it seem I will not have that any more. Unless I have strong arguments, why I should keep them.